# vs String in .NET

Tags: vb.net, string, types

I used developerfusion.com to convert a snippet of my C# code to VB .NET and I noticed the String type translated into [String].

I tried Google and Searching SO to no avail so I will ask the community is there a difference between [String] and String? And if so what is/are the difference(s)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The converter probably did that because it didn't recognise the string type and thought that it was a class defined in your code.

You can put brackets around identifiers to use keywords. You could create your own `[String]` class that would be different from the built in `String` class, but that could of course easily get confusing...

```
Public Class [String]
   Public Value As Integer
End Class

Dim s As New [String]
s.Value = 42
```

Answer (score 8):

In VB.Net, the [] surrounding a word is used to allow a keyword to be used as a normal identifier.  So using [String] means I want to identify something with the word String and not the VB keyword String.

Comment: Thank Jared!  Your answer and Guffa's were acceptable.  So I up voted your answer and accepted Guffa's due to Guffa's answer came in before yours and included an example.  Again Thank you to both of you!

Comment: For c# developers it is the equivalent of @ in front of variable names like @this

Answer (score 1):

Brackets usually indicate a variable name that using a reserved keyword. Did you name string variables String?

Answer (score 1):

Brackets can be used in VB.NET to allow VB.NET keywords to be used as user defined names. For example, you could create a class called Integer, even though there is already an Integer keyword in VB.NET:

```
Public Class [Integer]
End Class
```

Hope this clarifies!